# As a Beast Conclave revised ranger, how do I calculate my ape companion's statistics?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, unearthed-arcana

I'm trying to do the maths on the statistics for an ape companion for the [UA revised ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) beastmaster. However, I'm a little confused with its +5 to both attacks. Is that based on Strength + Prof? I thought the ranged rock attack should be based on Dexterity but that also seems to have a +5 even with a Dexterity modifier of +2.

I am planning to add +2 to strength; how will that affect the modifier to attacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thrown weapons (like a rock) are a special case of ranged attacks - if the weapon thrown is considered a melee weapon, you use the ability modifier you would have normally used in a melee attack, rather than automatically using dexterity - so, usually your strength modifier, unless fighting with a Finesse weapon. From the weapon properties in the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties):

> **Thrown.** If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack. If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon. For example, if you throw a handaxe, you use your Strength, but if you throw a dagger, you can use either your Strength or your Dexterity, since the dagger has the finesse property.

It looks like the attack modifier for the [ape's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ape) rock throw has been calculated as if it was a melee weapon being thrown, rather than an intrinsically ranged weapon, so the attack uses the strength modifier. Improving the ape's strength should benefit both attack modes.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, thrown weapons use STR bonus; Aimed weapons use DEX bonus. The +5 for thrown rocks is Strength modifier + Proficiency.

> Ability Modifier: The ability modifier used for a melee weapon attack is Strength, and the ability modifier used for a ranged weapon attack is Dexterity. Weapons that have the Finesse or Thrown property break this rule. (PHB 194)

Ability modifiers increase on even scores. So,if you add +2 to it's strength, the strength modifier will go up +1. 18 strength is +4.